# Android: do we have to manually create model classes?

Tags: android, model

I'm creating a model class, let's say it's called "History" that will interact with a SQLite Database.

Do we always have to manually create getters/setters/fields for the model class? Aren't there any auto-generators for this?

Example of a model class:

```
package com.example.fileexplorermanager;


public class History {

    //private variables
    int _id;
    String _file_name;
    String _full_path;
    String _file_type;

    // Empty constructor
    public History(){

    }
    // constructor
    public History(int id, String _name, String _full_path, String _file_type){
        this._id = id;
        this._file_name = _name;
        this._full_path = _full_path;
        this._file_type = _file_type;

    }

    // getting ID
    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    public String getFileName(){
        return this._file_name;
    }

    public void setFileName(String file_name){
        this._file_name = file_name;
    }

    public String getFullPath(){
        return this._full_path;
    }

    public void setFullPath(String full_path){
        this._full_path = full_path;
    }

    public String getFileType(){
        return this._file_type;
    }

    public void setFileType(String file_type){
        this._file_type = file_type;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Eclipse: Source -> Generate Getters and Setters...

Answer (score 6):

## Update

#### From Android Studio v3.0.1:

In Android Studio, by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>INSERT</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> for MacOS), you will have following choices (including your solution!):

- Constructor
- Getter
- Setter
- Getter and Setter
- equals() and hashCode()
- toString()
- Override Methods...
- Implement Methods...
- Delegate Methods...
- Super Method Call (When inside an *Override Method*)
- Copyright
- App Indexing API Code (Not available inside class extending *Fragment*.)

Select the option you want and select the methods. Done!

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Eclipse right click on source file -> Source -> Generate Getters and Setters... [image]

Comment: I'm going to accept Cseh's answer because he has a lower rep. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing provided by Android, but there are third-party libraries like ORMLite.